# How do I convert base 10 to any base using switch case inside a while loop?

Tags: java

(sorry for bad English.) Hello, I'm taking Pre-AP Computer Science 1 and my teacher gave me a project that wants me to create a code that converts base 10 to any base using switch case inside a while loop.
This is my main code.

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class TenToAny
{
   private int base10;
   private int newBase;

    //add constructors
   public TenToAny()
   {
       base10 = 0;
       newBase = 0;
    }
   public TenToAny(int b, int n)
   {
       base10 = b;
       newBase = n;
    }
    //add a set method
   public void setTenToAny(int b, int n)
   {
       base10 = b;
       newBase = n;
    }

   public String getNewNum()
    {
        String newNum="";
        while (base10<=1)
        {
            int a = base10 % newBase;
            base10 = base10/newBase;
            switch (a)
            {
                case 0: newNum = "0"; break;
                case 1: newNum = "1"; break;
                case 2: newNum = "2"; break;
                case 3: newNum = "3"; break;
                case 4: newNum = "4"; break;
                case 5: newNum = "5"; break;
                case 6: newNum = "6"; break;
                case 7: newNum = "7"; break;
                case 8: newNum = "8"; break;
                case 9: newNum = "9"; break;
                case 10: newNum = "A"; break;
                case 11: newNum = "B"; break;
                case 12: newNum = "C"; break;
                case 13: newNum = "D"; break;
                case 14: newNum = "E"; break;
                case 15: newNum = "F"; break;
            }
          }
        return newNum;
    }

    //add a toString method 
   public String toString()
   {
       return base10 + " base 10 is " + getNewNum() + " in base " + newBase;
    }
}
```

and this is my runner code.

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class TenToAnyRunner
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        //add test cases    
        TenToAny test = new TenToAny();
        test.setTenToAny(234, 9);
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

I called the method and got "234 base 10 is  in base 9".

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Comment: "please don't down-vote..." removed. Please keep the question text relevant to the problem itself. If you want to avoid down-votes and close-votes, then better to work on improving the question so that it is specific, on-topic for the site, and gives enough information to allow it to be answerable.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: I think getNewNum method is wrong but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two issues in getNewNum. The first is your while loop says `while (base10<=1)` so it does not get started in your test case. It should be `while (base10>=1)`. The other is that each subsequent case is resetting newNum as opposed to tacking characters onto it. Making these two changes made the code into:

```
while (base10>=1)
    {
        int a = base10 % newBase;
        base10 = base10/newBase;
        switch (a)
        {
            case 0: newNum = "0"+newNum; break;
            case 1: newNum = "1"+newNum; break;
            case 2: newNum = "2" +newNum; break;
            case 3: newNum = "3"+newNum; break;
            case 4: newNum = "4"+newNum; break;
            case 5: newNum = "5"+newNum; break;
            case 6: newNum = "6"+newNum; break;
            case 7: newNum = "7"+newNum; break;
            case 8: newNum = "8"+newNum; break;
            case 9: newNum = "9"+newNum; break;
            case 10: newNum = "A"+newNum; break;
            case 11: newNum = "B"+newNum; break;
            case 12: newNum = "C"+newNum; break;
            case 13: newNum = "D"+newNum; break;
            case 14: newNum = "E"+newNum; break;
            case 15: newNum = "F"+newNum; break;
        }
      }
```

which indeed yielded:

```
234 base 10 is 280 in base 9
```

It may be there are some other things to test, but that should at least fix the present issue.